# Wp-ecommerce and All in one SEO plugin to show meta on product category

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wp-ecommerce and All in one seo plugin in my website.
I am unable to add box to include title, description and keywords for product category page.
Is All in one SEO provide this functionality?

Please HElp

Comment: Yes! [All in One SEO Pack](http://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack) provide this functionality.

Comment: By default it is showing no box for this. If you let me know how I can acheive it. It will be helpfull. Thanks